# Реальный приоритет инкремента/декремента

Tags: javascript

Собственно вот в чём вопрос: если верить https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence , то у операторов инкремента/декремента не самый высокий приоритет. Но на практике, вне зависимости от формы(постфиксная или префиксная – не важно), они выполняются раньше, чем оператор группировки или вызов функции:

```
function test(i) {
  console.log(i);
  return(i);
};

let i = 0;

i++ + test(i); //1
```

То есть, сначала выполняется увеличение переменной на 1, затем в функцию передаётся уже увеличенное значение, а затем, так как форма инкремента постфиксная при выполнении бинарного сложения используется его значение до увеличения, то есть 0. Обернув функцию в скобки, ничего не поменялось.

Получилось, что инкремент выполнился раньше, чем функция, хотя судя по таблице приоритетов, такого быть не должно.

Или это особенность взаимодействия унарных и бинарных операторов(в данном случае плюса, который выполняется слева направо)? Облазал кучу форумов – ответа так и не нашёл. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь сможет мне объяснить, желательно простыми словами;)

Comment: Почему не должно? Отталкиваться нужно от сложения: сначала вычисляется первый/левый операнд (`i++`), затем второй (`test(i)`). Затем происходит самое сложение. Какие там приоритеты у операторов, используемых внутри операндов, - не важно.

Comment: Сравнение всегда идет между двумя операндами, в вашем примере происходят два сравнения, сначала ++ и +, выбирается первый, т.к. у него выше приоритет, потом идет сравнение + и вызов функции, выбирается второй, т.к. выше приоритет, и в последний момент выполняется сложение.

Comment: Теперь понятно, всё-таки отталкиваться нужно от ассоциативности бинарных операторов.

Comment: Даже наверное точнее сказать, что унарный оператор внутри выражения, всегда выполнится раньше бинарного, но не сохранит порядок с другими унарными операторами, если они находятся внутри разных операндов бинарных операторов.

Comment: @halfPeiceOfGangsta да. Так как у сложения приоритет ниже, чем у инкремента и вызова функции, то инкремент и вызов функции являются операндами сложения, которые по ассоциативности вычисляются слева направо, без учета приоритетов между собой.